# Is it possible to play flv/mp4 in phonegap?

Tags: video, cordova, flv, mp4

Is it possible to have a builtin player that plays flv/mp4 in phonegap?
I don't want to use third party apps, just builtin player that opens links.

Comment: both of them are just containers and i don't think that the phonegap team would build such a big project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for playing flv you need third party library because non of the ios or android support it naively but for mp4 you can use phonegap media api :

```
 // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Update media position every second
    var mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // get media position
        my_media.getCurrentPosition(
            // success callback
            function(position) {
                if (position > -1) {
                    console.log((position) + " sec");
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
```

for more information see : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html